# require.js and jquery init

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am testing require.js to get a more structure way to load library dependencies. But I cannot seem to get a basic example to work with jQuery. The only thing I can see I am doing differently than the examples is that my JS libs are on a different subdomain.

Code:

```
<script src="http://scripts.test.com/arkon-main.js"></script>
<script src="http://scripts.test.com/require.js"></script>
```

arkon-main.js

```
 var require = {    
 baseUrl: 'http://scripts.test.com',
paths: {     
    page: 'http://mypage.test.com/script/page/',
    jQuery: 'jquery',

},
shim: {
    'jQuery': {
        exports: '$'
    }
}
```

};

The page module (this is PHP code that serves the JS, hence the URL):

```
require(["jQuery"], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('YES');
    });
});
```

In the HTML:

```
<script>require(["page"]);</script>
```

In my "Network" view in Chrome it looks (almost) good, I can see arkon-main.js, require.js, page module and jquery loaded successfully. However:

My problem is that page is loaded before jQuery which causes that part to fail. I do not understand why, since I would expect the require to load jQuery then run the code inside?

I have tried different versions and also the examples on requirejs web-page, but I cannot make it work in my environment. I just want a basic setup where I can use require to load libraries as they are needed when I load new pages (in the right order).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery must be requested as `jquery`, all lower caps because the name `jquery` is hardcoded in the jQuery code. (Unfortunate, but that's the way it is.) Also, if you are using jQuery from 1.9.x onwards (and maybe even earlier versions too), you **must not** specify a shim.

These two issues only serve to mislead RequireJS and may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to: 1. replace jQuery with jquery 2.remove the shim parameter from config. It gives me the following errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.js:6,Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined .js:80 (page module). I am using jQuery 1.10.x